# The "proper" way to atomically replace all contents in a PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the project I have been recently working on, many (PostgreSQL) database tables are just used as big lookup arrays. We have several background worker services, which periodically pull the latest data from a server, then replace all contents of a table with the latest data. The replacing has to be atomic because we don't want a partially completed table to be seen by lookup-ers.

I thought the simplest way to do the replacing is something like this:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM some_table;
COPY some_table FROM 'source file';
COMMIT;
```

But I found a lot of production code use this method instead:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE some_table_tmp (LIKE some_table);
COPY some_table_tmp FROM 'source file';
DROP TABLE some_table;
ALTER TABLE some_table_tmp RENAME TO some_table;
COMMIT;
```

(I omit some logic such as change the owner of a sequence, etc.)

I just can't see any advantage of this method. Especially after some discoveries and experiments. SQL statements like `ALTER TABLE` and `DROP TABLE` acquire an [ACCESS EXCLUSIVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES) lock, which even blocks a SELECT.

Can anyone explain what problem the latter SQL pattern is trying to solve? Or it's wrong and we should avoid using it?

Comment: I speculate the intent is one of two things:  (1) To minimize the time when the table is unaccessible or (2) To ensure that either the whole table or nothing is available (no partial data).

Comment: Instead of drop + recreate table i prefer `delete` + `insert from tmp_table`. It's fast, but might be a problem for a while. You should consider using `materialized views` - data truncated from table, have no influence in that kind of query. To update `materialized view` you have to execute command `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html

Comment: The first solution might take a **lot** longer as `delete` is really slow on large tables

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How about using `TRUNCATE`? It also acquires an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock, but avoids creating a new table and swapping back.

Comment: But then the table is locked and not accessible during the `COPY` process. Using a second table avoids that - the "real" table is only locked for a very brief moment

Comment: @Lemjur Thanks for reply, I'm new to PostgreSQL and I haven't heard about materialized views before. Why saying `delete` + `insert from tmp_table` could be a problem? AFAIK `DELETE` is MVCC-safe and doesn't block a `SELECT`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `COPY` locks a table-this makes much sense! But how do you know that? I haven't found any words in the online documentation saying this. Seems it must be mentioned somewhere implicitly.

Comment: They are different. The difference is that in the second case the DROP could cascade into deleting VIEWS or removing FK-constraints from+to this table. Also, the ownership+permissions for the table would need to be reconstructed.

Comment: @brk because after `delete` command, users will query for incomplete data untill `insert` statement ends. Solution depends on how long users can wait for informations. Once i've made alternate schema to import all needed informations to multiple tables, and then i've performed `delete` + `insert into dest_schema.table_name select * from alter_schema.table_name`.

Comment: @Lemjur I think I misunderstood what you said. You mean `DROP` + `RECREATE` _is fast but might be a problem for a while_ , right? Users won't see incomplete data if `DELETE` and `INSERT` are put in the same transaction.

Comment: @brk I've meant `delete` + `insert`, but it depends on way you gonna implement that. If you go 1 transaction per table, then queries joining multiple tables may return informations from updated one and these waiting in queue (old data).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried with two `psql.exe`, `copy from stdin` in the first and `select` in the second. `select` didn't get blocked while copying. So sorry but it seems you are wrong.

Comment: @brk: then you didn't use `truncate`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Got it. `COPY` itself never locks a table. Thanks.